# The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request

Tags: wcf

I get the exception "The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request" and i dont have any clue why.

The web.config look fine - but maybe i dont see the problem

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="524288" />
  </system.web>

 <system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="ServiceLibrary.ServiceProxy"                                              behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">

    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.IServiceProxy">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>  


<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

The code ( server )

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceProxy
{
    [OperationContract]   
    ImageData GetImgInfo( byte[] analyzingTargetBitmap );   
}

[DataContract]
public class ImageData { ... }
```

Client code

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy" closeTimeout="00:15:00"
                openTimeout="00:15:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:15:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:15:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:50025/ServiceProxy.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy" contract="ServiceReference1.IServiceProxy"
            name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: **What** are you doing?? **How** are you tryign to access your service?? Show us some code!! We can't possibly guess from just your config what you're doing.....

Comment: You're still not showing us **how** you call this service!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WCF error is really not explaining the problem but i had a similar issue. It might be that the object you are sending through is too big or it has too many items in the array.

You have to change the config to accept bigger messages.

Comment: btw, another thing that could cause this is accidentally configuring mismatching bindings on the service and client.  For example, you set up the client with basicHttpBinding and the service with netTcpBinding