# cant access my WCF service thru other machine in the same network

Tags: wcf

I wrote the most simple wcf service that have one method

```
// return a+b
int ICalc::add(int a, int b)
```

When I try to access the service through local machine - I get the result with no problem. 
But try to access from other machine i cant get the service.

I try to define

```
<security mode="None"/>
```

from the client machine.

I try to define web page 'default.htm' to see if I can access and see the web page (to be more clear .. I can access and see the default.htm page).

I try to access using the IP and using the machine name - but nothing! Nothing work.

I define my service as WAS.

Someone can help me here ?

Service web.config file: ( 192.168.1.117 is machine ip - but I try also using localhost and machine name .. nothing help )

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10000000" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceLibrary.ServiceProxy" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ServiceLibrary.IServiceProxy">
        <identity>
          <dns value="192.168.1.117:50025"/>
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.117:50025/ServiceProxy/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>  
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Client `app.config` file : (here I also try to use the machine ip and try also use the machine name -  I also try to disable the firewall of the client and the server ... nothing help)

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false" >

              <security mode="None"/>

                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.1.117/ServiceProxy.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IServiceProxy" name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceProxy">
            <identity>
                <dns value="192.168.1.117" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Post relevant parts of both `web.config` files (server and client) and we'll try to see if you done something wrong there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056514/the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the port in the client config file - but its still does not help and i still fail to open the the service.

( fail in the r.open()

```
ServiceProxyClient r = new ServiceProxyClient();
r.Open();
```

)

Comment: Post it as comment to my answer, not new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the port in the client config file:

```
address="http://192.168.1.117:50025/ServiceProxy.svc"
```

Edit: in case it still fails, browse directly from the client machine to the `address` using browser: what do you get?

Also, what error do you get exactly?

Comment: Since he's hosting in IIS/WAS, the defined base address is not relevant - the virtual directory in IIS will dictate what address to bind to...

Comment: So the problem is with the virtual directory in the IIS ? How i deal with it ? what do you think i need to do / check ?

Comment: @Yan not sure yet - what happens when you browse directly to the address? What error do you get when invoking the WCF from the client?

Comment: browse directly to some web page ( default.htm ) give me the right page. calling with WFC client give me the exception "there was no endpoint listenning at http://192.168.1.117:50025/serviceProxy.svc that could accept the message ... "

Comment: yes, try this also - i get message "500 - internet server error. there is problem with the resource you are looking form and it cant be displayed"

Comment: I check with sniffer - the request is getting to the server machine from the right ip ( cliend ip )

Comment: its can be bacause of something that i need to change / define in the IIS ?

Comment: @Yan You need to have it hosted properly on IIS, yes... I don't know how your server is configured so it's hard to tell what exactly is wrong sorry.

Comment: My service define as a WAS => where can i find how to config of the iis using wcf and was config ?

Comment: @Yan well, you'll find everything here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx looks like you have lots to read and learn so take the time. :)